# Why DBD::mysql doesn't exit in Perl Package Manager 4.19 Perl Version 5.20?

Tags: mysql, perl, bugzilla, dbd

I want to install DBD:mysql in Perl version 5.20 but in PPM when I type DBD:mysql in search box it doesn't exist at all. So what is the problem? How can I solve it.

[image]

Comment: Two colons. `DBD::mysql`

Comment: PPM uses distribution names with dashes (`DBD-mysql`) instead of module names with double colons.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see on the official page: DBD-MySQL is not shipped with Active state Perl v. 5.20 on Windows. Reason: the build has failed.

https://code.activestate.com/ppm/DBD-mysql/

Maybe, you could try an older version: 5.16, where it exists.

Comment: So there no way to install DBD-mysql in that perl version

Comment: @user3098538 I think, no.

Comment: @user3098538, Strawberry Perl v5.20.1 includes DBD::mysql.  ActiveState seems to have been neglecting it's Perl port for the last couple years.

Answer (score 1):

Does Activestate take a distribution name with a dash as separator (DBD-mysql) or a package name with two colons as a separator (DBD::mysql)? I could bet it's not a single colon...

Comment: It was really not a question, just a note that (s)he probably has a wrong separator...

Comment: @arco444, I interpret this as a "Jeopardy style" answer.  It is also correct.  In `PPM` one must use dashes in preference to colons.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @GuidoPreite, You are incorrect.  While the english usage is non-standard, it is a fine answer to the question.

Comment: @tjd, my comment is the auto-generated from the review center. The answer (as you call it "Jeopardy style") basically is "the product X has feature Y? I bet not". Now I don't remember if this answer was flagged for poor content or because looks like a comment, however if you feel it provide an answer, you can edit/improve it removing the "Jeopardy style", in this way everybody on SO will benefice from an improved answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because the module is called "DBD::mysql" (with two colons) but you typed it as "DBD:mysql" (with only one colon).

Answer (score 0):

Whilst earlier builds of DBD::mysql failed to build for ActivePerl 5.20, the latest version of DBD::mysql (4.029) [successfully compiled](https://code.activestate.com/ppm/DBD-mysql/) and is now available for ActivePerl 5.20/Perl Package Manager!